# Inverted axis and accelerometer in Crosswalk after finish activity in portrait

Tags: android, webview, accelerometer, screen-orientation

In my activity i'm using crosswalk for rendering a threejs scene. The activity is using 
`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

When my activity is launched the first time, everything is fine. But when i leave the activity via backbutton while holding the phone portrait-wise the axis / accelerometer gets inverted the next time the activity is started. Also my threejs scene gets rotated 90degrees clockwise.

When pushing the homebutton and going back over history to the activity fixes the axis and rotated content